# AWS Cognito in local environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a NET 6 Web REST API service (->RDS PostgreSQL) deployed as Lambda. I develop it on Local Windows and use local PGSQL. When deploy it to Lambda it works with RDS. Now I need to add Authentication and Authorization methods to use RBAC.

What can I use as Cognit Identity Provider in local environment during development ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check this out.

https://github.com/jagregory/cognito-local

or

You could convert postman of [Amazon Cognito](https://www.postman.com/api-evangelist/workspace/amazon-web-services-aws/collection/35240-8631617c-c1ed-4e14-b0cd-77e4410753c4?ctx=documentation) to open api spec and from open api spec into your familiar backend stack